# How do I hunt for vulnerable points in the geth interface?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Part of Rannoch: Get Fighter Squadrons quest, at the last Geth access point, the infected nodes keep regenerating and I'm asked to hunt for the vulnerable infection. How do I identify this? I couldn't find an obvious hint :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the path of the infected nodes away from the data point until it has a second light area, that is the weak point you will need to hit first to be able to break the infested node.

Comment: yep, some places it was annoying as hell to backtrack and find out which one's the vulnerable node